# Анимация орел и решка

Tags: android, android-animation

Задача: сделать анимацию типа орел/решка. То есть сначала пользователь видит активити потом происходит анимация, активити поворачивается на 180 и пользователь видит уже тыльную сторону предыдущей активити, которая собой представляет уже другую вьюху.

Есть следующий код:

```
    ObjectAnimator flip = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(rootLayout, "rotationY", 0f, 180f);
    flip.setDuration(3000);
    flip.start();
```

В результате его выполнения, вьюха поворачивается на 180 и в конце я ее вижу уже как отзеркаленую по горизонтали. У меня вопрос: как можно заранее слепить эти две вьюхи в виде монеты и сделать нужную мне анимацию? Возможно есть какие то другие способы, отличные от того что я привел выше.

Comment: Очень похоже на [публикацию на официальном сайте](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/animation/cardflip.html).

Comment: я лично ничего не понял в вопросе, что у Вас не получается? что вы хотите сделать? анимацию вы написали, так в чем вопрос тогда?

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei анимация которую я привел работает щас для одной вью, а мне надо, что бы при повороте ее на 180 градусов  - я видел не ее тыльную часть а уже другую View

Comment: всё теперь ясно, разделите анимацию на две части. там есть момент когда у вас View1 полностью свернута, вам необходимо отловить этот момент, поменять на View2 и доиграть вторую часть анимации.